# How to detect the center of each "block" in an image (matrix) in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection

See the image below, there are 9 "blocks" and I wish to detect their centers

[image]

Comment: Detect the edges and then do algebra? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean the pixel with the largest value or the "centre of mass" of the bright events?

Comment: Hi John, this image is the extracted features by CNN and I wanna to detect the center in order for automatic annotation for original images.

Comment: Hi David, yeah that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use openCV:

**1) Find objects:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[reference](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

**2) Find centers of the object:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('star.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)

cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
```

[reference](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: It seems that you forgot this line in the second section:
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)